# mSATA drive swap for Wireless card

Tags: pci-express, pci, msata

I was doing some cleaning of my older Acer Aspire 3860 laptop and noticed that my wireless card looks alot like an mSATA drive. I have not been inside laptops too often (clean, add RAM) but never really had a part stick out at me.

Is this a PCIe slot that I can put anything in or is it a dedicated wifi slot?

There looks to be a deal on a drive and I am wondering if anyone knows that a swap for the wifi is  possible?

If I look up Atheros - it is described as a wireless G wifi mini PCIe.

Here is an image of the two cards.

Top card is mSATA, bottom is Wifi.
[image: compare]

Comment: Is there any options to use miniPCI mSATA card in place of wifi card?
May be with some kind of adapter will helps?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible!

A quote from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#mSATA):

> Mini-SATA, which is distinct from the micro connector, was announced
>   by the Serial ATA International Organization on September 21, 2009.
>   Applications include netbooks and other devices that require a smaller
>   solid-state drive. The connector is similar in appearance to a PCI
>   Express Mini Card interface, and is electrically compatible; however,
>   the data signals (TX±/RX± SATA, PETn0 PETp0 PERn0 PERp0 PCI-express)
>   need connection to the SATA host controller instead of the PCI-express
>   host controller.

Comment: interesting. The revo drives seem to work in a desk top PCIe, but not mSATA in a pci mini?

Comment: @CarlB that is because the OCZ RevoDrives have a PCIe and not an mSATA interface. Therefore you can connect those to a PCIe slot but not to an mSATA slot.

Comment: you are correct, found were someone tried and failed.